# CSS issue with different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a basic contact page for my website. I'm struggling to get it looking good in varying resolutions.

My laptop is 1368x766 and my monitor is 1920x1080.

The elements that set to absolute are moving around, the top image isn't moving...all other elements are moving... I'm so confused:

CSS:

```
 body {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/JN0YSkP.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

p {
position: absolute;
top: 225px; 
right: 410px; 
font-size: 32px;
}
p2 {
position: absolute;
top: 420px;
right: 974px;
font-size: 28px;
}

p3 {
position: absolute;
top: 420px;
right: 570px;
font-size: 28px;
}

p4 {
position: absolute;
top: 420px;
right: 142px;
font-size: 28px;
}

.LI
{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
z-index : 2;
top: 510px; 
right:1050px; 
}

.CV
{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
z-index : 2;
top: 490px; 
right: 620px; 
}

.mail
{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
z-index : 2;
top: 510px; 
right: 196px; 
}

.Divider
{ 
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1; 
top: 380px; 
right: 28px; 
padding-bottom: 20px
}

html { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Benjamin Edwards | Web Designer | West Sussex</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Benjamin Edwards is a Web Designer and IT Project Manager from West Sussex. Say hello!">
    <meta name="keywords" content="benjamin, edwards, IT, project, manager, photoshop, web, designer, worthing, west sussex">
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6gBN3LF.png">
    <p>Hi! I’m Benjamin, a Worthing based</br>Web Designer and IT Project Manager.</p>
    <p2>Connect on LinkedIN:</p2>
    <div class="LI">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/benjaminedwards86">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KEqGBV3.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <p3>Download my CV:</p3>
    <div class="CV">
        <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jtsjxpb9xqdpdw/Benjamin%20Edwards%20-%20CV.docx?dl=1" download="benjamin-edwards-CV.doc">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ce0Zzgi.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <p4>Send me an email:</p4>
    <div class="mail">
        <a href="mailto:benjamin.edwards86@gmail.com">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KQV7Eip.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="Divider">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/B4TiKRT.png">
    </div>

</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p69ex6n0/)

Comment: What is your exact goal? Just as sidenote, a resolution on that size isnt normal for most of the people, you should consider on having a minimum width of at least ~900px that you dont need to scroll on an x-axis on a browser window. Also you should consider of lower the amount of used `position: absolute;`

Comment: @Grief-Code just trying to make sure it looks good in different resolutions / browsers. Just want everything to be centered and centered within the boxes.

Comment: Yea I understood it, after i added you the JSFiddle link :-) But `position: absolute` is not the best solution for this. See my answere, i made it simply with a list and its centered always ;-) Also you could reach the same goal with flex-box, but this would work only on newer browser (IE9+)

Comment: @Grief-Code ah yeah that's working, looks neater and works in different resolutions as I'd expect. 

Slightly confused, how would I move the img of me down a bit? Padding?

Comment: With margin :-) Checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p69ex6n0/2/ You can choose any value for margin top that it fits to your idea how it should look like ;-)

Comment: @grief-code Ahh! Got that, great! Thanks. Only one more question (I think), how do I get the list close to the top image?

Comment: Once again the magic of `margin-top` :-) Checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p69ex6n0/3/ at `ul{ }` you can set once again the distance ;-)

Comment: Brilliant, I've got that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: OK....sorry! One more.

Comment: @grief-code How would I move the elements within the boxes around. The CV image for example is slightly too low...?

Comment: Hey Banjamin, sorry for my late reply, but I hand't time until now. You can simply add some classes, i made another fiddle update for you: http://jsfiddle.net/p69ex6n0/4/ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As exmaple how simple it can be for you, i created a jsfiddle: 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p69ex6n0/1/)

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/6gBN3LF.png">
<p>Hi! I’m Benjamin, a Worthing based</br>Web Designer and IT Project Manager.</p>
  <ul>
   <li><h1>Connect on LinkedIN:</h1>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/benjaminedwards86">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KEqGBV3.png">
    </a>
   </li>
   <li><h1>Download my CV:</h1>
    <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jtsjxpb9xqdpdw/Benjamin%20Edwards%20-%20CV.docx?dl=1" download="benjamin-edwards-CV.doc">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ce0Zzgi.png">
     </a>
    </li>
    <li><h1>Send me an email:</h1>
     <a href="mailto:benjamin.edwards86@gmail.com">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KQV7Eip.png">
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/JN0YSkP.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    min-width: 900px;
}
img {
    margin: auto 20px;
}

ul {
   height: 275px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 10% auto;
    border: 3px solid #31C2A9;
    min-width: 900px;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    border-right: 1px solid #31C2A9;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 275px;
    min-width: 275px;
}
ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

You get rid of all the css selectors and simplify your code :-)
And there is no single position absolute ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Its always wise to make a fiddle about the problem you are having. 
Coming to the issue about elements moving around, Its because you have absolutely placed ALL the elements and hard coded the values. Like:

```
p {
position: absolute;
top: 225px; 
right: 410px; 
font-size: 32px;
}
```

Since at different browser sizes, the resolution changes and so does the placement of the divs, your elements are moving awry ( Since you have absolutely positioned them only to ONE browser dimension.

So what you should do:
First, you should make sure you understand when should a div be absolute and when should it be relative.

I'll give a thumb rule: If you want to position an element with respect to a div. Make it position absolute and its parent, position: relative.

You could make your website responsive using Bootstrap. But you could also give measurements in % and prevent distortions.

If I am to do one:

```
p3 {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
right: 30%;
font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

If you dont exactly know whats happening, you should spend time studying %, em measurements etc.

If you can create a fiddle and show your code, We can help you fix it.

Answer (score -3):

You can use [CSS media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/) for this.

Media Queries is a CSS3 module allowing content rendering to adapt to conditions such as screen resolution (e.g. smartphone screen vs. computer screen).

With media queries, we'll take this to a new level. Rather than looking at what device it is, we will look at what capabilities the device has. More specifically, we will look at the following:

1. height and width of the device height and width of the browser
2. screen resolution orientation of the device (for mobile phones and

   tablets; portrait or landscape)

CSS2 allows you to specify stylesheet for specific media type such as screen or print.
Now CSS3 makes it even more efficient by adding media queries.

You can add expressions to media type to check for certain conditions and apply different stylesheets. For example, you can have one stylesheet for large displays and a different stylesheet specifically for mobile devices.

It is quite powerful because it allows you to tailor to different resolutions and devices without changing the content.

**Example**:

The following CSS will apply if the viewing area is smaller than 600px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .class {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

If you want to link to a separate stylesheet, put the following line of code in between the `<head>` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="small.css" />
```

**Multiple Media Queries**:

You can combine multiple media queries. The following code will apply if the viewing area is between 600px and 900px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .class {
    background: #333;
  }
}
```

**Device Width**:

The following code will apply if the max-device-width is 480px (eg. iPhone display). Note: max-device-width means the actual resolution of the device and max-width means the viewing area resolution.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .class {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin I have edited the whole answer..please reopen the answer...nd Why I got downvotes for this?

Comment: It isn't closed, it has just been downvoted a lot. You got downvotes because 3 people thought it was a bad answer.

Comment: @Quentin now is it also bad answer?